# Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have

Tags: android, react-native

I tried to run the `react-native run-android` through my React Project. After that, I got an error like the following.

```
  Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat installDebug...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Users/DELL/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.pom
         file:/C:/Users/DELL/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.jar
         file:/F:/Android/react/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.pom
         file:/F:/Android/react/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.0.1/appcompat-v7-23.0.1.jar
     Required by:
         AwesomeProject:app:unspecified
         AwesomeProject:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.27.2
   > Could not find com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Users/DELL/.m2/repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/23.0.1/recyclerview-v7-23.0.1.pom
         file:/C:/Users/DELL/.m2/repository/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/23.0.1/recyclerview-v7-23.0.1.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/23.0.1/recyclerview-v7-23.0.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/23.0.1/recyclerview-v7-23.0.1.jar
         file:/F:/Android/react/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/23.0.1/recyclerview-v7-23.0.1.pom
         file:/F:/Android/react/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/23.0.1/recyclerview-v7-23.0.1.jar
     Required by:
         AwesomeProject:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.27.2
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/C:/Users/DELL/.m2/repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.1.1/support-v4-23.1.1.pom
         file:/C:/Users/DELL/.m2/repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.1.1/support-v4-23.1.1.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.1.1/support-v4-23.1.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.1.1/support-v4-23.1.1.jar
         file:/F:/Android/react/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/support/support-v4/23.1.1/support-v4-23.1.1.pom
         file:/F:/Android/react/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/support/support-v4/23.1.1/support-v4-23.1.1.jar
     Required by:
         AwesomeProject:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.27.2 > com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.10.0 > com.facebook.fresco:drawee:0.10.0
         AwesomeProject:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.27.2 > com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.10.0 > com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline:0.10.0
         AwesomeProject:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.27.2 > com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.10.0 > com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline:0.10.0 > com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-base:0.10.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 17.502 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

I installed Android SDK and set Android Home and Path Environmental Variable successfully. But I am still getting the same error.

I also installed Gennymotion on my pc for creating virtual android device.

Comment: Can you share more output from the command you ran?

Comment: I updated the post with full output. Now please check and replay.

Comment: Do you have the android support library properly setup ? https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html. What Build tools version ands support library versions are you using. You can also open the android folder of the react-native project from android studio. See if it complains about Build tools or version not installed.

Comment: So what I need to next. Please tell me step by step.

Comment: I installed almost every package in the Android SDK Manager. 23.0.3 | 23.0.2| 23.0.1 | 24| 19.1| etc

Comment: I suggest you try to build the project through Android Studio, it might detect the missing dependency and suggest you to download it.

Comment: I have same issue. What does  `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1` refer to in SDK Manager? What needs to be checked to get this installed?

Answer (score 36):

You might check the permissions on Android/Gradlew
They should be **755** not **644**.

Run `chmod 755 android/gradlew` inside your app root folder.

Then run `react-native run-android`.

And it should work again.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thank you!

Comment: There is no such 755 not 644.

Comment: You're a saviour!!

Answer (score 6):

1. Open Android Studio
2. Open anyproject or create an empty project
3. Find Action (CMD + SHIFT + A) type: AVD Manager
4. Hit enter to open AVD Manager
5. click the little Pencil icon (Edit this AVD)
6. click on change (we need Android 6 (23) over there)
   [image]
7. then select Android 6 (23) and click OK
   [image]
8. Now click on **PLAY** button next to Edit (pencil), and keep the emulator running
9. Now open Terminal, **cd TO_YOUR_PROJECT**
   and then type: `react-native run-android`

ref: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 3):

Fixed the error with the following in .bash_profile

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_171.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/saif-ams/MyFiles/applications/androidsdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Comment: I had multiple versions of JDK so the first line of your answer solved it for me.

Comment: Saif, is it safe to assume that if we have zsh, we need to do this inside of `.zshrc`?

Comment: You can just set them on your terminal and then run the android build.

Answer (score 2):

in my case i created

> local.properties

file with `sdk.dir=C\:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk` inside **android** directory

Answer (score 1):

In this [React Native AwesomeProject tutorial](https://shift.infinite.red/getting-started-with-react-native-development-on-windows-90d85a72ae65#.y4kls7mj0) the author notes that the project's Android Studio build version may have to be updated in the project's `build.gradle` file.

If you are using the newest version of Android Studio you may have to do that too if your tutorial is a bit older.

Find your project's `build.gradle` file which should be located in    `\AwesomeProject\android\app\` folder.

In `build.gradle` file find `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"` and change to `buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"`

Note that there may be another `"23.0.1"` string in your file but that is for the Android support version and should stay unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem as well. It was a permission problem in the project folder. I solved this with:

```
sudo chown -R userName \AwesomeProject
```

Comment: what about in windows?

Answer (score 0):

I just revoked permissions and re-accepted them again. It sounds silly, I know, but I also tried other options first, until I saw that Cordova did not recognize my device either. I just unplugged my cell phone to go from school to my home. I hope that for some it can be solved that easily.

Answer (score 0):

If your are facing this error while trying to setup **Android Development Environment** for a **React-Native project** :

Run `touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile` on your terminal. This will open up the file containing the path for your environment variables. Simply add your exports here, save it and close.
(Latest React-Native exports for the Android Build can be found here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

Make sure you have at least one Virtual Device installed.

Finally run `npx react-native run-android`