# Could not install the app on the device - react native on windows 10

Tags: react-native

Everytime I try to launch a react native project I got this error

> Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for
>   details. Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device
>   connected and have set up your Android development environment

I reinstalled nodejs, python and jdk using choco as suggested on official docs. Every single packages is installed as well as sdk 23.0.1

[image: screenshot]

I can see my virtual device if I run `adb devices` USB debugging is activated and it's running android 6.

I setup ANDROID_HOME path in environment variables, I'm using same sdk path as you can see in the picture. I also setup another one for JAVA_HOME and Python.

My PATH looks like this:

[image: PATH]

I just don't understand what I'm supposed to do. I'm using a surface pro 4, Windows 10. I can run projects using expo. I literally tried everything, restart computer, start cmd using admin, create new virtual devices, uninstall everything and start from scratch, it just don't work.

Comment: What  Error  or Exception do you get . @youssef

Comment: @syed-zain-ali I do not see any error, it just run the metro bundler and stuck at loading dependency graph

Comment: chmod 755 android/gradlew reffer this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900737/make-sure-you-have-an-android-emulator-running-or-a-device-connected-and-have)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is to delete all java `JDK` and reinstall v8 / change `JAVA_HOME` to the new path.

Also changing `gradle-wrapper.properties`file for each project you want to run

```
# update gradle to latest version
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4.1-all.zip
```

Sometimes it dosen't compile with v4 so I have to use v3. React native is definitely confusing.

Comment: Glad you resolved your issue, but I have same kind of issue, but unable to resolve the issue. Have checked the environment variables, restarted my machine. `adb devices` command do list *emulator* and any connected *device*. But no success.

Answer (score 7):

You have pointed out two issues; first, make sure you have an android emulator running. To do that, you run `adb devices` and you say you can see you device.

The other issue is with the environment. To make sure your environment is setup properly for android, go to the root of your react-native project. Open the android project using `android studio`.

All errors with your environment will show up, use the automatic fixes provided by android studio. Clean the project in android studio. Close studio and go back to command line, run `react-native run-android`

Everything should work now.

Comment: This is smart, using studio I found that I have a problem with gradle and java versions, in gradle-wrapper.properties there's this line distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4.1-all.zip do you know which version I should use? I tried v4

Comment: You can use the latest version available.

Answer (score 4):

When doing `react-native start` it will intentionally hang at "Loading dependency graph" (its not really hanging, its just waiting to receive build/bundle signals). This is correct. You have to open a second terminal then do `react-native run-android`.

If you get errors, then `cd android` in your project folder then run `./gradlew clean`, then after that do another `react-native start` then `react-native run-android`.

Comment: this is not solving my issue, run-android by default launch bundler in another terminal console so I still got the same error.

Comment: @YoussefS close bundler and try the `./gradlew clean` first.

Comment: I can't run this command it should be gradlew clean, it throw me an Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: zip END header not found. What does it means?

Comment: @YoussefS first you have to `cd android`, move into the android directory of your project.

Comment: first of all this command is for mac and I clearly stated that my issues is on windows os, second why do I need to delete build directory? It's a fresh new project. Thank you for the reply

Answer (score -3):

after install dan update environment JDK now I can install app on my device